# How to use a field for determining index in Logstash without saving it?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using logstash for the first time and can't figure out how to determine index on a parsed field without persisting it.

This is my configuration file:

```
input {
  http {
    port => 31311
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "headers", "message" ]
  }

  grok {
    match => [ "name", "^(?<metric-type>\w+)\..*" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{metric-type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Json example sent to the `http` plugin:

```
{
  "name": "counter.custom",
  "value": 321,
  "from": "2017-11-30T10:43:17.213Z",
  "to": "2017-11-30T10:44:00.001Z"
}
```

This record is saved in the `counter-2017.11.30` index as expected. However, I don't want the field `metric-type` to be saved, I just need it to determine the index.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you tried using the [@metadata field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata)?

Comment: I haven't seen that functionality. I have tried implementing it as suggested here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-let-logstash-splits-event-field-values-and-assign-it-to-metadata-field/57833/2 but it seems it is not supported with grok. The maintainer suggested to put it in another field, but it seems that would bring us right back to my question if I am not mistaken...

Comment: Hmm yeah I haven't tried it with the regex syntax you use... The idea with putting it in another field isn't that bad, as you can remove your `metric-type` field afterwards with the [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field).

Comment: I have actually done exactly that, but it does seem a bit 'hacky'. If there is no way to put the grok matched pattern directly to `@metadata`, I guess using a temporary field is good enough. Posting my solution as an answer.

Comment: Agreed, maybe you could replace `"^(?<metric-type>\w+)\..*"` with a grok pattern... Then using the `@metadata` field directly should be no problem.

Comment: `you could replace "^(?<metric-type>\w+)\..*" with a grok pattern` I am a bit confused by that statement, I thought `^(?<metric-type>\w+)\..*` IS a grok pattern?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160205/discussion-between-phonolog-and-aturkovic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `grok` to put my `metric-type` into a field since grok pattern does not support `[@metadata][metric-type]` syntax. I have used a `mutate` filter to copy that field to `@metadata` and then removed the temporary field.

```
input {
  http {
    port => 31311
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "headers", "message" ]
  }

  grok {
    match => [ "name", "^(?<metric-type>\w+)\..*" ]
  }

  mutate {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][metric-type]" => "%{metric-type}" }
    remove_field => [ "metric-type" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][metric-type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

-- EDIT --

As suggested by @Phonolog in the discussion, there is a simpler and much better solution. By using grok keyword matching instead of regex, I was able to save the captured group directly to the `@metadata`.

```
input {
  http {
    port => 31311
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "headers", "message" ]
  }

  grok {
    match => [ "name", "%{WORD:[@metadata][metric-type]}." ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][metric-type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```